# Ajax Sign in with Devise on Grape API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, api, authentication

I have a rails application which I'm building using Grape and Devise to hand Authentication. The scope of the app is to present an API to a JavaScript front end (so no ERB here, at all).

After adding the Warden/Devise related helpers part of the class api < Grape::API looks like this

```
resource :ticket do
    desc "Returns all tickets for a the requesting user; for admins, returns all tickets."
    get :all do
        authenticated_user
            @all_tickets = Ticket.where(user_id: current_user.id)
        end
    end
end
```

It works perfectly, it calls "authenticated_user" and if returns a user is logged in, it returns the data. If not it returns 401 - Unauthorized (using ajax calls asking for json responses). The user of course will have to go to http://domain.com/users/sign_in first to log in. Then it will redirected to the application page where all these calls can be made.

Now, for the sake of the application flow, I need to have the sign in form to be ajax-based. From whenever the user is in the app.

I have followed the tutorial [Ajax Login with Devise](http://jessehowarth.com/2011/04/27/ajax-login-with-devise) and many others. But this one made more sense to me. However I'm having very strange results.

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
$('#login').click(function (e) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.domain.com/users/sign_in?',
    type: 'post',
    data: {remote: true, commit: "Sign in", utf8: "✓", user: {remember_me: 0, password: "12345678", email: "admin@domain.com"}},
    format: "json",
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });     
});
```

Note that I'm using cors/rack to perform cross domain calls.
There are 2 scenarios:

1 - When I fire this call I get status 200 OK. However the cookie set is not enough to perform an api call that requires authentication. The api call hence, returns 401 - Unauthorized.

2 - If I set "remember_me" to true (or 0), and click the login button it returns 200OK the first time. It doesn't send cookies along the request (because there are no cookies yet as I'm signed out). The response is 200 OK with the rails cookie in the response headers.

However after that call, the second time I click it the login button, it returns "302 Moved Temporarily" and then another request hits domain.com/ - After that I'm authenticated. When I do an API call that needs auth the data is returned. This time the cookie was sent (the one got from the first login attempt) and it returned another cookie in the response headers. This one is different from the one I sent and I think it's because of CSRF. Everytime the cookie is sent a new one is thrown back with a new token.

While performing API calls I have to use "xhrFields: { withCredentials: true}" to be able to send the cookie along the requests so devise can authenticate the API caller. So the data, if I'm logged in using the default Devise form, is returned with no hassle.

Another alternative was to send along the CSRF token along the request (got from the meta of the HTML), but as I explained above, I'm building a client side JS client and the pages don't render from within rails itself.

Is there a way to log in with Devise using ajax, without having to make the call twice?

Thanks in advance!
DD